# Startup finished in 39s (firmware) + 6s (loader) + 1min 1s (kernel) + 15s (userspace) on SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, systemd, firmware

Can't believe myself but it's true. It became like this at one moment, may be after some `apt-get upgrade`, I did'n have time to resolve it before.
Laptop Asus N550JV with SSD and 16GB RAM installed, Ubuntu 16.10(ten, yep), all the packages are up to date, Windows 8 in dual boot. Everything was super fast before, but now it takes 39 seconds before I see `grub`'s menu.

Kernel version is `4.8.0-22-generic`

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
      7.075s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      2.746s dev-sda5.device
      2.673s postgresql@9.5-main.service
      2.176s docker.service
      2.091s snapd.firstboot.service
      2.088s apparmor.service
      2.055s systemd-update-utmp.service
      1.973s apt-daily.service
      1.817s networking.service
      1.115s keyboard-setup.service
      1.110s teamviewerd.service
      1.084s systemd-udevd.service
      1.003s wpa_supplicant.service
       868ms docker.socket
       868ms snapd.socket
       826ms ModemManager.service
       821ms irqbalance.service
       814ms speech-dispatcher.service
       786ms NetworkManager.service
       781ms apport.service
       780ms grub-common.service
       712ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       705ms systemd-resolved.service
       702ms lightdm.service
       701ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       533ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       324ms systemd-random-seed.service
       201ms dev-sda6.swap
       107ms bluetooth.service
        74ms upower.service
```

went to check my UEFI setup, brb.

Comment: The kernel was updated from 4.4.0.42 to 4.4.0.43 on my last automatic Ubuntu 16.04 update today. What does your `name -a` reveal? Under Ubuntu 16.10 you should be on Kernel version 4.8.0.xx I believe.

Comment: Also try an immediate reboot. Sometimes it is faster but in your case perhaps not. Can you include the first screen output from `systemd-analyze blame` in your question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The slow part in the boot process is the UEFI loader (firmware) here, not GRUB (loader) or Ubuntu (kernel+userspace). I'm sorry, but any problems that appear before GRUB starts to load are not really related to Ubuntu and therefore probably off-topic(?)... Please enter your UEFI setup menu and check all the options there, maybe you can find something strange. It could also be trying to identify some hardware, likely a USB device that doesn't respond properly. This could slow it down drastically. Did you add any new hardware recently?